# Does Marlin input shaping compensate vibration on all X, Y and Z axes?

Tags: marlin, input-shaping, resonance-compensation, vibration-compensation

The Marlin Firmware supports Input Shaping (M593) as described in the [Marlin documentation](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M593.html) writing:

> Set the Input Shaping damping factor and/or frequency (in Hertz) **for axes that support it.**

But the parameters shown under the Usage section suggest only axis X and Y are supported? It is possible to use input shaping (in Marlin) to compensate vibration on all X, Y and Z axes?

Comment: Unless you're doing non-planar printing, Z axis input shaping shouldn't affect print at all. The distances and accelerations in Z are so low in comparison to X,Y travel they just don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of December 2023, Z-axis Input Shaping is not possible in Marlin firmware. Marlin only supports Input Shaping on the X and Y axes.

There is a [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/26474) to implement Z-axis Input Shaping on Marlin.